# Python pandas question, reading and writing DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any problem with back-to-back writing/reading a DataFrame like this? I have tested and it works. But I have a couple of questions and here they are. Do I need some `multiprocessing`, or `time`, or `threading`, or `async` which looks unsupported, to do some waiting? But what about a large DataFrame? Like 20 cols and 1,000,000 rows?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import util
df = util.testing.makeDataFrame()

# Write
df.to_excel('file.xlsx')
# Read
df_1 = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: Nope, no problem with this. Don't need to do anything.

Comment: "What about a large data frame?" You will have to read about how `to_excel()` and `read_excel()` work. If you need to optimize, you will have to write your own versions of these yourself. I suspect that they are as optimized as it gets, though.

Comment: I would recommand using a pickle format (read_pickle). Much much faster writting and reading files. No encoding issues, and no index created in your written files

Comment: Unless you've specifically programed it differently, most things in Python are done linearly, meaning the next thing won't happen until the previous thing has finished. Therefore, there's no problem with you current setup.